# How to read what color/ RGB value the camera is pointing at on Android using CameraPreview?

Tags: android, colors, android-camera, rgb

Let me preface this being that I am pretty new to Android. I searched all over for help on this and pieced together what I have so far.

So my intent is to use the Camera Preview to read an RGB value that the user points the camera at and save that after prompting the user for each item. Example, I ask show me a shirt and after the user confirms I store that color in an array where I hold the colors. Planning to do something with those after this part.

Right now, the code I have opens the camera view with a close (x) button in the top right but I have hit a wall on where to go next. I implemented a decode function from the Ketai Project to decode the RGB value from Pixel data. Could use some clarification on that, how could I average what it gives me into a color? For-loop possibly?

I'm familiar with ImageView after seeing some of that but I want to read the RGB values more real-time as the user shows me.

```
package ricardo.colormatch;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;

import java.io.IOException;

public class CameraView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.callback, Camera.PreviewCallback
{
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;
    private Camera.Parameters parameters;
    private Camera.Size previewSize;
    private int[] pixels;
    private int[] myPixels;
    private static final String TAG = "Cam";



public CameraView(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);

        mCamera = camera;
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

        // Here we want to get the holder and set this class as the callback where we will get camera data from
        mHolder = getHolder();

        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        try {
            //when we create the surface, we want the camera to draw images in this surface
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            mCamera.setPreviewCallback(this);
            parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
            previewSize = parameters.getPreviewSize();
            pixels = new int[previewSize.width * previewSize.height];
            mCamera.startPreview();
        }catch(IOException e) {
            Log.d("ERROR", "Camera error on surfaceCreated " + e.getMessage());
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }

    }


    @Override
    //make sure before changing surface that preview is stopped, it is rotated than restarted
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int format, int w, int h) {

        //checks if surface is ready to receive data
        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null)
            return;

    try

    {
        mCamera.stopPreview(); //stops the preview
    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        // If camera is not running
    }

    //Recreate camera preview

    try

    {
        parameters.setPreviewSize(w, h);
        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.d("ERROR", "Camera error on surfaceChanged" + e.getMessage());
    }

}
    @Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera){

        Log.d("Cam", data.toString());
        decodeYUV420SP(pixels, data, previewSize.width, previewSize.height);
        Log.d("Cam", pixels.toString());

    }

    //From the Ketai Project image processing
    void decodeYUV420SP(int[] rgb, byte[] yuv420sp, int width, int height) {

        final int frameSize = width * height;

        for (int j = 0, yp = 0; j < height; j++) {
            int uvp = frameSize + (j >> 1) * width, u = 0, v = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < width; i++, yp++) {
                int y = (0xff & ((int) yuv420sp[yp])) - 16;

                if (y < 0)
                    y = 0;

                if ((i & 1) == 0) {
                    v = (0xff & yuv420sp[uvp++]) - 128;
                    u = (0xff & yuv420sp[uvp++]) - 128;
                }

                int y1192 = 1192 * y;
                int r = (y1192 + 1634 * v);
                int g = (y1192 - 833 * v - 400 * u);
                int b = (y1192 + 2066 * u);

                if (r < 0) {
                    r = 0;
                } else if (r > 262143) {
                    r = 262143;
                }

                if (g < 0) {
                    g = 0;
                } else if (g > 262143) {
                    g = 262143;
                }

                if (b < 0) {
                    b = 0;
                } else if (b > 262143) {
                    b = 262143;
                }

                rgb[yp] = 0xff000000 | ((r << 6) & 0xff0000) | ((g >> 2) & 0xff00) | ((b >> 10) & 0xff);

            }
        }
    }

    //destroy the camera in the surface
    //Note : Move code into activity if using more than one screen
    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder){

        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.release();

    }

}
```

MainActivity:

```
package ricardo.colormatch;

import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Camera mCamera = null;
    private CameraView mCameraView = null;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try{
            mCamera = Camera.open(); //open the camera

            }catch(Exception e) {
            Log.d("ERROR", "Failed to get camera: " + e.getMessage()); //get error message if problem opening camera
        }

        if(mCamera != null){
            mCameraView = new CameraView(this,mCamera); //create our surfaceView for showing the camera data
            FrameLayout camera_view = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.camera_view);
            camera_view.addView(mCameraView); // add surfaceView to layout
        }

        //button to close the app
        ImageButton imgClose = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgClose);
        imgClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }


}
```

What I get from the logs:

```
[I@20928f56
[I@20928f56
```

And it just repeats as the app is running, why is that?

Comment: Looks like you have a lot of pixels, maybe millions, in the pixels array to consider...

Comment: @DougStevenson Ah so the decode works correctly. That makes sense, Hm, because what I was thinking is I want the user to focus the camera on a particular object lets say a red shirt the object of all those pixels might render a red picture. Probably do a little more research on how to average all those for the color.  That would take a considerable amount of resources to go through though. 

Or is there a easier way? Let's say have a point to focus on and take the color or pixels in that area. Would you happen to think a way I could do that?

Comment: You're getting beyond my area of expertise, but yeah, you have the right idea.  You'll need some way to offload all that computation onto another thread, and maybe not do it for every single frame the camera produces.

Comment: @DougStevenson I'll give it a shot. Right now seeing if I can make a bitmap from that found some information on how to get the average color from that. Worst case scenario probably try following open source project and adding to it or choosing a whole new project altogether. Thanks for your help.